# Ionic/Angular: Inject dynamic CSS-styles from API for dynamic content

Tags: css, angular, ionic-framework, ionic3

I'm stuck with following problem:

I recieve an dynamic HTML-Content-Snippet from an API with certain classes and ids applied.
Additionally there a dynamic and individual CSS-Stylesheet I can access through this API, too.

What i got so far:

`encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None,` is important, otherwise the classnames etc. would be changed/extended by Angular.

What I can't get to work is to apply the styles received from the API to the component.

The first idea was to put the style-promise-result directly here: 

`@Component({
  selector: 'page-dynamic',
  templateUrl: 'dynamic.html',
  encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None, 
  style: mycssapi
})`

or somehow inject it afterwards. Didn't get it working.

The second idea was to add `<style type="text/css" [innerHTML]="mycss?.styles">`  or this:
`<style type="text/css">
   {{mycss?.styles}}
</style>`

Someone an idea how to solve this?

A sketch of the process: Get dynamic HTML-Code-Snippet and the CSS-Styles -> Inject it in a Component

Thank you in advance!
Markus

Comment: Did you get to solve this? I'm facing a similar issue.

Comment: No sorry. Didn't dig deeper-

Comment: for what's worth I ended up attaching a manually created style element to the body.

Comment: I have the same problem. Did you find a solution for this?